# why pip install a git repo fails in this requirements file?

Tags: python, git, pip

When trying to install a git repo through pip, for example:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/kayluhb/django-admin-bootstrapped.git@cms-2.4
```

it just works. But then when putting that same line in a requirements file (if that matters this requirements file is called from another requirements file) then pip can't find the branch:

```
Could not find a tag or branch 'cms-2.4 '
```

What did I miss here? An argument like -e or something?

UPDATE:
I have tried another one without the '@' version:

```
git+http://github.com/jmoiron/johnny-cache.git
```

When I manually pip install it, it just works too. But then in the requirements file it fails with:

```
error: The requested URL returned error: 400 Bad request while accessing http://github.com/jmoiron/johnny-cache.git /info/refs?service=git-upload-pack
fatal: HTTP request failed
Command /usr/bin/git clone -q "http://github.com/jmoiron/johnny-cache.git " /tmp/pip-GE7AOI-build failed with error code 128 in None
```

Comment: I've added `git+https://github.com/kayluhb/django-admin-bootstrapped.git@cms-2.4` to the requirements.txt and ran `pip install -r requirements` - no errors, installed successfully.

Comment: @alecxe I think the problem lies with the `@` symbol. I've seen it mess up my git cloning on several occasions.

Comment: I have just tried without the @ and receive another error, maybe it's unrelated and the @ is really a problem too.

Comment: it looks like calling it from another requirements file might break it. Calling with ./ works. And the @ seems to not like #comments I had one and removed it and it does not break anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with `git+git` instead of `git+https`?